# Azure API Management - how to force HTTPS on the new Developer Portal

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a custom domain associated with my APIM instance with the corresponding SSL certificate.
I want to force HTTPS on the Developer portal (the new one) and unfortunately, I'm not able to find where I can do that in the APIM configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a custom domain with a certificate in the Azure portal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it is done. But despite that, when I browse the URL with HTTP instead of HTTPS, it works.

Comment: Could you please submit a support ticket with the service name.

Comment: Just to inform that this is a known issue not yet resolved: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/388

Comment: I can confirm that this is fixed.